# Herança PHP e Doctrine: Duplicate definition of column

Tags: php, postgresql, herança, doctrine

Boa tarde.

O seguinte erro está acontecendo:

**Erro: Duplicate definition of column 'numg_usuario' on entity 'Usuario' in a field or discriminator column mapping.**

Minha classe Usuario extends de PossuiGrupo.

Então o mapeamento da Classe Usuário é a seguinte:

```
 /**
  * @Table(name="ge_usuario")
  * @Entity
  */
  class Usuario extends PossuiGrupo {

  /**
   * @var integer
   *
   * @Column(name="numg_usuario", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @Id
   * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
    protected $numgUsuario;
```

E dentro da classe Possui grupo está assim:

```
 /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="ge_grupo_usuario")
     */
    class PossuiGrupo extends ModelObject {

   /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="numg_usuario", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Usuario")
     */
    protected $usuario;

   /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="numg_grupo", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Grupo")
     */
    protected $grupo;

    public function __construct($usuario, $grupo) {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->grupo = $grupo;
    }
```

Existe alguma forma de trabalhar assim com Doctrine, sendo que não posso alterar a estrutura do banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode complementar a pergunta com o modelo do seu banco de dados atualmente?

Comment: Bom dia, editei a pergunta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O que eu faria seria criar uma relação *many-to-many* entre usuários e grupos. Dessa forma, fica implícito que:

- Um usuário pode fazer parte de diversos grupos;
- Um grupo pode possuir diversos usuários.

Dessa forma, essas seriam as classes.

Classe `Usuario`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ge_usuario")
 */
class Usuario
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="numg_usuario", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Grupo", inversedBy="usuario")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ge_grupo_usuario")
     */
    public $grupos = [];
}
```

classe `Grupo`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ge_grupo")
 */
class Grupo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="numg_grupo", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Usuario", mappedBy="grupos")
     */
    public $usuarios = [];
}
```

Deve ter um ou outro aspecto para customizar, mas no geral é mais ou menos isso. :)